# FreeBSD - how to exclude some pattern with grep?

Tags: grep, freebsd

*FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1 FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1 #0     root@releng2.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64*

*grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD*

Hi. I want to check availability of Asterisk process, so I use this command:

```
ps aux | grep /usr/local/sbin/asterisk
```

But the output is not relevant bacause it contains two strings (the first is for Asterisk process and the second is for grep process):

```
asterisk 44044   9.8  2.1  866912 133628  -  Is   14:35     121:27.41 /usr/local/sbin/asterisk -n -F -U asterisk
root     44242   0.0  0.0   14796   2484  4  S+   09:50       0:00.27 grep /usr/local/sbin/asterisk
```

So I want to exclude "grep" string. 
In Linux I can use flag -v, but what should I do in FreeBSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer: Change the pattern so it doesn't show up in ps, but still matches, for example use square brackets to search for

```
/usr/local/sbin/asteris[k]
```

Maybe better answer: Use a program like [`pgrep`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1) to "look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes"

Comment: Thank you, the "-f" flag of pgrep is solution.

Comment: So the command will be: pgrep -lf /usr/local/sbin/asterisk

Comment: Welcome:) I usually use the `-f` flag on linux, and the bsd `-l` flag looks equivalent to linux's `-a` flag (list full command line & pid)